# printing disabled components

Tags: css, primefaces

I have some disabled components on some pages. When I send the page for printing or save the page as PDF, the disabled components doesn't get printed or saved to PDF.

It can be replicated in the showcase. When you print or save the page with disabled components from the browser.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf

FF 25.0.1 not ok
IE 9 ok
Chrome ok

Answer (score 0):

First, what do you mean by "disabled components", do they `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` or how are you disabling them?

Apart from that, you can make a print/pdf exclusive stylesheet by adding this to your `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Comment: Yes, I have that piece of code. What I meant is some of my components have disabled="true". And if I print the page with the disabled components using FF 25.0.1, it is printed as blank. No problem with IE and Chrome.

Comment: Can you set a jsfiddle?